# Building filters based on multiple documents in MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following objects stored in MongoDB:

```cs
public class User
{
   public string UserId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string LocationId { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
   public string LocationId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Truck
{
   public string TruckId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

`Truck`, `Location`, and `User` each have their dedicated collection in the database.

The app receives the `UserId` as an input, and it should find the trucks associated with the `UserId`. How can MongoDB driver achieve this goal in C#?

Comment: I don't know C#, but a possible MongoDB query could be something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KUfBuc2x_fs).

Comment: From your model classes, I don't see the relationship between `User` & `Truck`. Maybe `Truck` class missed the `UserId` property? Would be better if you can show the sample documents for these collections.